# Different output in fstream. How the token work?

Tags: c++

I am new to programming. I have a "data.txt" file with the content:

1 0 2 9 3 8 4 7 5 6:0.

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<sstream>
#include<iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include<limits>


std::ifstream& GotoLine(std::ifstream& file, unsigned int num) {
    file.seekg(std::ios::beg);
    for (int i = 0; i < num - 1; ++i) {
        file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    return file;
}
struct tokens : std::ctype<char>
{
    tokens() : std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}

    static std::ctype_base::mask const* get_table()
    {
        typedef std::ctype<char> cctype;
        static const cctype::mask *const_rc = cctype::classic_table();

        static cctype::mask rc[cctype::table_size];
        std::memcpy(rc, const_rc, cctype::table_size * sizeof(cctype::mask));

        rc[':'] = std::ctype_base::space;
        rc[' '] = std::ctype_base::space;
        return &rc[0];
    }
};

int main() {
    int i;
    std::vector<int> v;
    using namespace std;
    std::ifstream file("data.txt");

    GotoLine(file, 4);

    std::string line4;
    std::getline(file, line4);

    std::stringstream ss(line4);
    ss.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new tokens()));
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> begin(ss);
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> end;

    while (ss >> i)
        v.push_back(i);

    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, my output is:

0 2 9 3 8 4 7 5 6 0

Then I try to delete ss in behind `begin(ss)` in below code:

```
std::stringstream ss(line4);
        ss.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new tokens()));
        std::istream_iterator<std::string> begin(ss);
        std::istream_iterator<std::string> end;
```

Then I have another ouput:

1 0 2 9 3 8 4 7 5 6 0

This is the output I want but then I try  adding "ss" next to the `end`:

```
ss.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new tokens()));
            std::istream_iterator<std::string> begin(ss);
            std::istream_iterator<std::string> end(ss);
```

Then I have a new ouput:

2 9 3 8 4 7 5 6

Can you guys explain to me how this works?

Comment: `istream_iterator`'s constructor reads one element from the stream. So every time you construct one, you swallow a number (since you don't actually use these iterators, and don't retrieve those numbers they've extracted).

Comment: thanks for your rely . But what  do u mean with"dont actually use these iterators"?.is that mean those iterators are no use in my code? Can u give me some examples??

Comment: I quite literally mean that you've declared those variables, but have never used them afterwards.